# change sf symbol weight/size in TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui, size, tabbar, sf-symbols

This a a sample TabBar code:

```
struct TabBar: View{
@State var current = 0
var body: some View{
    TabView(selection: $current) {
        
         View0()
            .tag(0)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "anySystemImageName")
                Text("")
            }
         View1()
            .tag(1)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "anySystemImageName")
                Text("")
            }
         
    }
}
}
```

How do I change the font and size of icons/text? Have already tried `.font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))` after Image(systemName: "Any") and after `TabView` brace and none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the font of the tab bar like this:

```
init() {
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)], for: .selected)
}
```

However, I am not aware if you can change the image size. I think the icon in tab bar have a fixed size. Not sure if you can change them in `UIKIt`

**Edit:** You can just pass any UIFont. If you want a different weight there is systemFont(ofSize: weight:) available like this

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. And what about changing the weight?

Comment: Edited above.. you can pass any UIFont to it. There is systemFont(weight)

Comment: If you want to apply a computed property as font size, use the above snippet in onAppear() instead of using init().